# spark.executor.extraLibraryPath is overriding the path instead of appending

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am setting an extra library path to the Spark's executor (in order to run a udf based on a C++ library).
When providing the extra library via the `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath`, I am seeing that the library path is being overridden instead of being appended.

Here is an example of seeing it:

```
 spark-shell -Dmaster=yarn-client --conf "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/path/to/mylib"
```

And inside the Spark shell, invoking the following shows that the executor's LD_LIBRARY_PATH is indeed not proper:

```
scala>  sc.parallelize(1 to 1).map(x => System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")).collect
res0: Array[String] = Array(/path/to/mylib:)
```

It seems that there was some fix in [SPARK-1719](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1719), but I am not sure that fix is correct.
Is there a better way to append a library path to the executor's runtime?

Comment: Which spark version are you using?

Comment: What happened when you execute the map command, when running spark-shell without the --conf? do you get additional paths?

Comment: I am currently using Spark 1.5.0 and without the conf setting, I am getting a list of libraries for hadoop/lib/native for jar under spark/lib etc. I have not seen yet if it is fixed in newer versions of Spark